# Bootstrap SB Admin 2: button text-alignment not working in Chrome

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome

I am using the Bootstrap framework with SB Admin 2 theme for an application, having some buttons, eg:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-circle btn-outline btn-xl">UV</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-circle btn-xl">Kl S</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-circle btn-outline btn-xl">Kl 15</button>
```

This is, how they should be displayed (and actually are in Firefox) with correct text alignment (sorry, I cannot post images yet): 
http://i123.photobucket.com/albums/o308/spinfun/firefox2.jpg

This is, what Chrome displays: 
http://i123.photobucket.com/albums/o308/spinfun/chrome2.jpg

So my question is: How can I make Chrome display those buttons with horizontally centered text?

EDIT: I have setup a real basic page with just those 3 buttons.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">

        <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <!-- custom CSS SB Admin-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/dist/css/sb-admin-2.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-circle btn-outline btn-xl">UV</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-circle btn-xl">Kl S</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-circle btn-outline btn-xl">Kl 15</button>

        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <!-- SB Admin Theme -->
        <script src="http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/dist/js/sb-admin-2.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The button texts are simply not displayed horizonztally centered in Chrome on each of the computers I use.

Without the SB Admin css the alignment is correct, but the buttons of course are not circular. So the problem has to be somewhere within the SB Admin stuff.

Comment: As I Cannot post more than 2 links: When the text is short enough, the alignment is centered even in Chrome: http://i123.photobucket.com/albums/o308/spinfun/chrome1.jpg

This is the Chrome log: http://i123.photobucket.com/albums/o308/spinfun/chromelog.jpg

Comment: It's  working fine in chrome..

Comment: Unfortunately it does not for me, as we can see in the 2nd image.

Comment: ok... can you post your html using fiddle..

Comment: i edited the question with a code sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to overwrite this class into your custom CSS file.

**CSS**

```
.btn-circle.btn-xl {
    padding: 10px 0;
}
```

SB Admin v2.0 theme has some predefined CSS which is causing the problem.

following class is having `padding: 10px 16px;` into its sb-admin-2.css file

```
.btn-circle.btn-xl {
    padding: 10px 16px;
}
```

Comment: This is great, thanks a lot, Nilesh. But could you, or maybe someone else, briefly explain why browsers behave differently?